# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'dialcall'

Tags: kivy

I want option of dialer in my app. and below is the function I used but I am getting above error.
def dial(self, *args):
call.dialcall()

Comment: We can't possibly help without seeing the full code.

Comment: thats actually the whole code i just didnt added kivy button ...thats it

Comment: No that is not the whole code.  `call()` is defined somewhere that you haven't shown.

Comment: no its from plyer import call

Comment: The import statement _is code_, that you didn't show us...